# XSLT and reusing value inside for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I have a number of article rows that might or might not have an order number. If the row misses an order number I want to show the latest existing order number as this articles order number.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Invoice> 
<InvoiceNumber>123</InvoiceNumber> 
<OrderNumber>head1</OrderNumber> 
<Rows> 
<Row> 
<ArticleNumer>1</ArticleNumer> 
<OrderNumber>line1</OrderNumber> 
<Quantity>1</Quantity> 
<Price>10</Price> 
</Row> 
<Row> 
<ArticleNumer>2</ArticleNumer> 
<OrderNumber><!--Here i want line1--></OrderNumber> 
<Quantity>1</Quantity> 
<Price>10</Price> 
</Row> 
<Row> 
<ArticleNumer>3</ArticleNumer> 
<OrderNumber><!--Here i want line1--></OrderNumber> 
<Quantity>1</Quantity> 
<Price>10</Price> 
</Row> 

<Row> 
<ArticleNumer>4</ArticleNumer> 
<OrderNumber>line2</OrderNumber> 
<Quantity>1</Quantity> 
<Price>10</Price> 
</Row> 
<Row> 
<ArticleNumer>4</ArticleNumer> 
<OrderNumber><!--Here i want line2--></OrderNumber> 
<Quantity>1</Quantity> 
<Price>10</Price> 
</Row> 
</Rows> 
</Invoice>
```

I use a for-each on the rows, and this seems to complicate the whole thing a bit. 
By using preceding-sibling I can get the latest existing value if the second line is empty. But if the third and forth row is missing the order number, how can I get it?

Creating a variable inside an if-statment does not work.
Using a template inside for-each gives me an error message. 
I was also thinking of using an counter that for every empty order number-row added 1 to it and using preceding-sibling but can't really see that solution in front of me.

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Andreas

Here is more of the exact code that I use:

Now it is gonna be a bit more confusing then. Specially when I am very unfamiliar with XSLT. Best_nr2 is Ordernumber from my sample. But:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Invoice/Tables/Table/TableRow">

<xsl:if test="string-length(Field [@Type='best_nr2']/text())&lt;2 and 
                                    string-length(preceding-sibling::TableRow/Field [@Type='best_nr2']/text())&lt;2 ">
                                <secondaryorder_number>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$dispatchOrderNr"/>
                                </secondaryorder_number>
                                </xsl:if>

                                <xsl:if test="string-length(Field [@Type='best_nr2']/text())&gt;2">
                                <secondaryorder_number>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Field [@Type='best_nr2']/text()"/>
                                </secondaryorder_number>

                                </xsl:if>



                                <xsl:if test="string-length(Field [@Type='best_nr2']/text())&lt;2 and 
                                string-length(preceding-sibling::TableRow/Field [@Type='best_nr2']/text())&gt;2 and 
                                preceding-sibling::TableRow[1]/Field [@Type='best_nr2']/text()&gt;2 ">
                                <secondaryorder_number>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::TableRow[1]/Field [@Type='best_nr2']/text()"/>
                                </secondaryorder_number>
                                </xsl:if>


                                <xsl:if test="string-length(Field [@Type='best_nr2']/text())&lt;2 and 
                                string-length(preceding-sibling::TableRow[1]/Field [@Type='best_nr2']/text())&lt;2 
                                and string-length(preceding-sibling::TableRow/Field[@Type='best_nr2']/text())&gt;2">
                                <secondaryorder_number>

                                </secondaryorder_number>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <lit_quantity>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(Field [@Type='lit_deliveredquantity'], ' ,',' .')"/>
                                </lit_quantity>
                            </LineItem>
                            <xsl:variable name="dispatchbestnr2" select="Field [@Type='best_nr2']/text()"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </LineItems>
                </Dispatchnote>
            </xsl:for-each
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row/OrderNumber[not(text())]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::Row[OrderNumber/text()][1]/OrderNumber"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first template is the identity template which copies nodes level by level, with the opportunity to override it for nodes you want to manipulate, and that is done in the second templates for the `OrderNumber` elements not having any text content.

Comment: Well the stylesheet is a complete sample to work against your input sample. Of course templates don't belong into a `for-each`. If you need help integrating my suggestion into your code then we need to see your code (although if it is a one template with lots of nested for-each approach then I am afraid combining both approach is difficult).

Comment: If I only had a way to save the latest existing Order number/best_nr2 and then print it all would be peachy.

Comment: Helpfull answer if I had not had a already functioning XSLT transformation except for just this smaaaaaall thing.

Comment: Martin, still active? Can you explain what the other template does? How can it move up the XML more than 1 preceeding sibling?

Comment: Andreas, there are two templates, the first one being the identity transformation that is the starting point, it makes a shallow copy of an element and then processes its attributes and child nodes with matching templates. That way, with only that single template, the input would simply be copied level by level, node by node. If we add other templates like the second one we can change the transformation, so for `OrderNumber` which don't have any text content we make a shallow copy of the element and populate it with the value of nearest preceding sibling `OrderNumber` having text content.

Comment: Great, now I feel that it is getting clearer! 

One tiny question tough, how do you get to the nearest preceding sibling with this: "../preceding-sibling::Row[OrderNumber/text()][1]/OrderNumber" ? I am having trouble seeing the iteration going backwards up the tree.

Comment: @Dreas89, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates about forward and reverse axis. `preceding-sibling` is a reverse axis.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I know about preceding-sibling, but not how it goes backwards more then once.